How to cutomize apache superset metric label?
I am using Apache superset for visualization data using charts. I have data like below

I have want to change sum(Reporting  Amount) in label to other column value like distinct Reporting Date.That mean I want to change sum(Reporting  Amount) to 22-10-202 dynamically.  Reporting Date row is same date like 22-10-2024 in Corporate Banking and Commercial Banking.
I am using chart . Here is the chart

I wan to change dynamically label instead of  SUM(Reporting  Amount) to Reporting Date . Here is the mark image

How to change sum(Reporting  Amount) to 22-10-202 in label?
Is it possible in Apache superset?
Please help me...

Currently, it is not possible to use a dynamically changed label in the Apache superset chart.
